# Why is char *str{ new char[10]{ "text" } } not working?

Tags: c++

I've tried the following code:

```
char *strPtr{ new char[10]{ "text" } };
```

but gcc versions before 11 result in an error:
`(error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive])`.

While

```
char str[10]{ "text" };
char *strPtr{ str };
```

which seems to be doing the same thing works. Why so?

Comment: The first allocates an array in the free store, but the second doesn't, so they don't do the same thing.

Comment: Likely a compiler bug. It works on clang and newer GCC. And I'm very sure the language spec allows this.

Answer (score 3):

This is GCC bug [77841](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77841).

It was fixed in GCC 11.

Obviously `new char[10]{ "text" }` is valid C++.